# Why is the canvas context not able to be written too inside the function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a canvas that is used to collect a user signature. The thickness of the line must change depending on the orientation of the tablet. When this script executes, I would expect the thickness of the line to be either 6 or 10, however it remains the default 1. Is someone able to explain why please?

```
var canvas = $("#signature_canvas")[0];
var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
var pendown = false;

function resize_canvas(){
    if(screen.height > screen.width){
        context.lineWidth = 6;
        canvas.width = screen.width;
        canvas.height = (screen.width / screen.height) * screen.width;
    }else{
        context.lineWidth = 10;
        canvas.width = screen.width;
        canvas.height = screen.height;
    }
};
resize_canvas();
console.log(context.lineWidth);
```

Comment: This is because when you change either the `width` or the `height` of the HTMLCanvas, all the context's properties are reset. So set it after you did change the size of your canvas and you'll be good

Comment: @Kaiido thank you very much